# Class and Static Method

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, append, class-method

1. define a class method getcirclecount inside circle which returns the number of circle objects created. hint: use classmethod decorator.
2. try accessing the class method using an object and the class.
3. to test the number of circles created and the area of each circle, provide the radius of each circle in the input.
4. output the total count of circles.

Here is what I tried

```
import os
import sys

#Add circle class implementation here
class Circle:
    pi = 3.14
    count = 0
    def __init__(self,radius):
        self.radius = radius
    
    @classmethod
    def getCircleCount(self):
        Circle.count += 1
        return Circle.count
  
    
    def area(self):
        area = self.radius **2 * Circle.pi
        return area

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        with open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w') as fout:
            res_lst = list()
            circcount = list()
            lst = list(map(lambda x: float(x.strip()), input().split(',')))
            for radi in lst:
            c=Circle(radi)
                res_lst.append(str(c.getCircleCount())+" : "+str(c.area()))
             fout.write("{}\n{}".format(str(res_lst), str(Circle.getCircleCount())))
```

For input `1,2`

expected output is

```
['1 : 3.04', '2 : 12.56']

2
```

Output I got:

```
['1 : 3.04', '2 : 12.56']

3
```

Here no of input given was 2 but output is 3

Comment: You shouldn't increment the circle count in the class method `getCircleCount` Put it in the constructor. The circle count should only go up if a new circle is created. Right now if you call `getCircleCount` 100 times. the circle count will increase by 100.

Comment: In addition to moving the increment to the constructor, you also need to add a decrement to the destructor __del__()

Comment: @luthervespers oh. nice catch

Answer (score 1):

```
class Circle:
    no_of_circles = 0
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius
    
    def area(self):
        Circle.no_of_circles += 1
        return round(3.14*self.radius*self.radius,2)
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

As object initialization `c=Circle(radi)` inside `for` loop, perform increment inside `__init__` method.

```
class Circle:
    pi = 3.14
    count = 0
    def __init__(self,radius):
        self.radius = radius
        Circle.count += 1
    
    @classmethod
    def getCircleCount(cls):
        return Circle.count
      
    def area(self):
        area = self.radius**2 * Circle.pi
        return area

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w') as fout:
        res_lst = list()
        circcount = list()
        lst = list(map(lambda x: float(x.strip()), input().split(',')))
        for radi in lst:
            c=Circle(radi)
            res_lst.append(str(c.getCircleCount())+" : "+str(c.area()))
         fout.write("{}\n{}".format(str(res_lst), str(Circle.getCircleCount())))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the last row, uses `count` instead of increasing.

`Circle.count` instead of `Circle.getCircleCount()`

**Edit: If you cannot edit **main****

### Option 1: Register new function when init

```
class Circle:
    pi = 3.14
    count = 0
    def __init__(self,radius):
        self.radius = radius
        self.getCircleCount = self._foo
    
    def _foo(self):
        Circle.count += 1
        return Circle.count

    @classmethod
    def getCircleCount(cls):
        return cls.count

    # ....
```

### Option 2: Use arg*

```
class Circle:
    # ...

    def getCircleCount2(*args):
        if len(args) == 0:
            return Circle.count
        else:
            Circle.count += 1
            return Circle.count
```

Alternatively, you can write the decorator like this [overload](https://www.codementor.io/@arpitbhayani/overload-functions-in-python-13e32ahzqt) or [multimethod](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=101605). I do like the first one due to its simplicity.

Comment: I updated the new version. It is just a quick solution.